# Account checkbox marks true when at least one Contact's checkbox is true

Tags: salesforce, apex

We currently have a custom checkbox field in contacts that we have set to true if they are the best person to call for that particular account. I want to create a checkbox field in accounts that will automatically mark true if it contains a contact with that particular checkbox marked true.

Essentially, I want an account checkbox called "Contains a best contact" that marks true when at least one of its contacts has the "Best person to contact" checkbox marked true.

Answer (score 0):

In general, your use case would be an example of a Roll-Up field between a Master and Detail objects.  However, you cannot make the Contact the detail to an Master object - let alone the Account.

You have a couple of options, but they aren't great.
You would need to create an Apex class to do the query of all the child Contact objects and update the Account accordingly.  This might be best to do this through an Update Trigger on the Contact objects to update the parent Account.  If the Contact record meets the criteria, then submit an update to the Account object using the Account ID in the Contact's Account field.

The warning here is that this is an extra DML statement on Contact updates.  If you do any bulk activity on Contacts this could exceed DML limits.  However, if you tailor the trigger correctly you may be able to limit how and when action is actually taken in the trigger.  The best would be to only enter the update code block if the Contact has an Account and the "Best person to contact" check box is being changed from "False" to "True" (you look at the old and new values in the trigger to determine that this change is occurring).

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a declarative solution without the use of triggers you could use the process builder along with flows in the process builder based on Contact you check for the checkbox being checked and ischanged so you dont process records that have already been processed and for the action kick off a flow passing in the AccountId as in input param.  The flow would query accounts that have the Id passed in with the checkbox unchecked and perform an update or quick update to check the box.

You would also have to do the inverse process builder  (different step in the same process builder or a different process all together doesn't really matter) where you check if the check box is not checked and ischanged and kick off a different flow (or same flow if you pass the checkbox state as an input parameter).  This other flow would search for accounts that have the checkbox checked by the Id, if it is found you can then search for contacts with the flag and if none are found update the account  to uncheck the checkbox.

But to update existing data you would need some code, which might need to be batched depending on how many records exist with he Flag set on Contact.

If you disable the ischanged option on the process builder process you can use the process builder and flows to update your data by doing something like:

```
update [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Flag__c = true];
```

which will trigger the flow.  Otherwise you need something like

```
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
List<Account> accToUpdate = new List<Account>();
for(Contact c : [SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Flag__c = true]){
    if(!accountIds.contains(c.AccountId)){
        accToUpdate.add(new Account(Id = c.AccountId, Account_Flag__c = true));
        accountId.add(c.AccountId);
    }
}
update accToUpdate;
```